# How to bootstrap a statistic calculed in a meta-analyis?

Tags: r, variance, nonparametric, bootstrap, meta-analysis

I have calculated a statistic in a meta-analysis of individual data and I want to bootstrap it to obtain the variance (no analytic expression is available) to make a test.

First, I was naively boostraping on the patients (R-code below):

```
bootFun <- function(df, i) {
    #i is the vector of row indices that boot will pass
    xResamp <- df[i, ]
    slope <- try({      
      stat_calc(xResamp)
    }, silent=T)
  } 

  b <- boot(df, bootFun, R = 300, parallel="snow")
var.boot = var(as.numeric(b$t), na.rm = TRUE)
```

But then I've had a doubt : maybe should I bootstrap on the study ?

Any suggestion on how should I proceed here ?

Comment: What does `stat_calc` do?

Comment: `stat_calc` calculate a difference between two groups A and B. Each study in the meta-analysis is divided into A and B. I have a study random parameter and a basline hazard estimated in each group A and B.

Comment: Maybe the details under `library(lme4); help("bootMer")` are useful?

Comment: It depends on whether you are using eventually aggregate or individual patient data as far as the inferential analysis is concerned. However, you definitely need to bootstrap study-wise.